# IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression

Tags: fortran

I need to generate data to Excel and I get an error cannot assing to a named constant. The problem is when I want to get `yw` using if, `yw` it depend on `lp` and if `lp` is 1 or `lp` is 50, then my `yw` is equal `y`, otherwise I must change my `yw`.

Here is the code

```
program dane

parameter (ndim = 50)
dimension lp(ndim), x(ndim)
real*8, dimension (ndim):: y0,dy,y,yw
integer x,xmin, dx
real*8 a,b,c
a=0.2
b=-1.0
c=10.0
xmin=-20
dx=1
n=50
call randomize

open(1,file='dane_excel.csv')
lp=0
x=0
y0=0
dy=0
y=0
yw=0

do i=1,n,dx

  lp(i)=i;
  x(i)=xmin+(i-1);
  y0(i)=a*x(i)**2+b*x(i)+c
  call random_number(r)
  dy(i)=3*sqrt(y0(i))*(r-0.5)
  y(i)=y0(i)+dy(i)


  write(*,*)lp(i),';',x(i),';', y0(i),';',dy(i),';'
  write(1,*)lp(i),';',x(i),';', y0(i),';',dy(i),';'


end do

if (lp.eq.1) then 
yw(1)=y(1)
else if (lp.gt.1 .and. lp.lt.n) then 
     do j=2,n-1
        yw(j)=(y(j+1)+2*yw(j)+y(j-1))/4
     end do
else 
yw(n)=y(n)
end if



close(1)
read(*,*)
end

!***************************************
subroutine randomize
!***************************************
!   inicjowanie przypadkowych wartości poczatkowych generatorów liczb losowych
!   e.z. 13.10.2016
!***************************************
integer clock,seed(20)
integer*8 clock8
call system_clock(clock)    ! czas systemowy w milisekundach
call srand(clock)           ! ustawienie przypadkowej wartości geberatora irand

clock8=time8()             ! czas w sekundach  od 1.01.1970
call random_seed(size=n)   ! odczyt w ilu bajtach zapisane jest ziarno generatora
seed = clock + 37 * (/ (i - 1, i = 1, n) /)       ! przypadkowe wartości ziarna
call random_seed(put=seed(1:n))   ! zapisanie ziarna do generatora
return
end
```

now the error looks like this:

```
C:\Users\SugiHime\Dropbox\Uczelnia\Foltran>gfortran ZALICZENIOWY1.f90 -o ZALICZENIOWY1.exe 

ZALICZENIOWY1.f90:45.4: if (lp.eq.1) then 1 

Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression

ZALICZENIOWY1.f90:47.22: else if (lp.gt.1 .and. lp.lt.n) then 1 
Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression 
C:\Users\SugiHime\Dropbox\Uczelnia\Foltran>Pause 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You should use `implicit none` in your programs.

Comment: now the error looks like this:
`C:\Users\SugiHime\Dropbox\Uczelnia\Foltran>gfortran     ZALICZENIOWY1.f90 -o ZALICZENIOWY1.exe
ZALICZENIOWY1.f90:45.4:

if (lp.eq.1) then
   1
Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression
ZALICZENIOWY1.f90:47.22:

else if (lp.gt.1 .and. lp.lt.n) then
                     1
Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression

C:\Users\SugiHime\Dropbox\Uczelnia\Foltran>Pause
Press any key to continue . . .`

Comment: You have `lp.eq.1`, but `lp` is an array, so `lp.eq.1` is also an array.  This isn't a valid condition in the `if` statement.  Perhaps `lp` is meant to be scalar, or you need some other condition.

Comment: If you have something to add the question can be re-opened if there are more details that would change the suggested solution. Edit the question if you have some more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help :)